# Send Email with SendGrid using Web API PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am confused with here with `$pass` and `$api_key`;
are they same? Because at first `$pass` is assigned with password of the SendGrid's username but then `api_key` is assigned with `$pass`.
If they are same they where we would use that `api_key` that we generated on SendGrid?
Please Help!

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$pass = 'PASSWORD'; 

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com',
    'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
    'html'      => 'testing body',
    'text'      => 'testing body',
    'from'      => 'example@sendgrid.com',
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with what you're trying to do:

- You should never send an API call to `sendgrid.com`, only `api.sendgrid.com`
- It looks like you're trying to use the v2 API with the Params. Since you're setting up a new script, you should use the [v3 API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html) which uses proper body JSON arguments, and is RESTful.
- Instead of setting up your own script, have you looked at the [SendGrid PHP Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)?
- For authentication in a script, you should always use an [API Key](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/api_keys.html), not your master username & password.

It looks like you got a really old example script for testing. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I don't know PHP, and I don't have a script. Did you check out the SendGrid PHP Library? That should give you a strong headstart.